# Import multiple ids in one record

Tags: laravel

I can add on item which is 'product_id' in each import my question is **How to add multiple product ids with multiple quantities in the same record and not one id ?**

```
Schema::create('imports', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('supplier_id');
            $table->bigInteger('branch_id');
            $table->bigInteger('product_id');
            $table->bigInteger('quantity');
            $table->double('cost',null,2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Controller

```
$import = new Import();
        $import->supplier_id = $request->supplier_id;
        $import->branch_id = $request->branch_id;
        $import->product_id = $request->product_id;
        $import->quantity = $request->quantity;
        $import->cost = $request->cost;
        $import->save();
```

Comment: Are `$request->supplier_id;` and `$request->quantity;` in array type?

Comment: my problem is not how to handle the request , my problem is how to store it in the database

Comment: I'm trying to figure out your problem. What is your mean in **Adding multiple product_id**?

Comment: I want to store one record in the data base which contains supplier_id , branch_id , total_cost , and multiple products with multiple quantities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to add multiple products associated to one import so, you have to use `one-to-many` relation. You need to create another model `ImportProduct` with a relation to `Import` model like so

```
class ImportProduct extends Model 
{

    ...

    function import()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Import::class);
    }

    ...
}
```

And in your `Import` model you will add

```
function products()
{
   return $this->hasMany(ImportProduct::class);
}
```

In your `import_products` migration you will add

```
...

$table->id();
$table->bigInteger('import_id');
$table->bigInteger('product_id');
$table->bigInteger('quantity');

...
```

You will remove `product_id` and `quantity` from `imports` migration.

Now in your controller you can add one import with multiple products using `products()` relation from `Import` model.

```
$import = new Import();
$import->supplier_id = $request->supplier_id;
$import->branch_id = $request->branch_id;     
$import->cost = $request->cost;
$import->save();

// $import->products()->associate($products);

//foreach ($products as $product) {
//    $import_product = new ImportProduct();
//    $import_product->import_id = $import->id; 
//    $import_product->product_id = $product->id;
//    $import_product->quantity = $product->quantity;
//    $import_product->save();  
//}
```